# Does the statistical power for testing regression coefficients depend on the number of model parameters?

Tags: regression, inference, overfitting, statistical-power

Given a generalized linear model (GLM), does the number of regression coefficients affect the power to detect a significant effect size for an individual regression coefficient i.e. as more variables are added to the model does statistical power decrease?

Comment: In general, yes. You could do a simple simulation yourself to investigate.